# AJAX returns correct values from array except ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have this controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetEvents() {

        //var project = _context.Project.SingleOrDefault();

        var events = _context.Project.Select(s => new {
            ID = s.ID,
            onSite = s.OnSite,
            onSiteTill = s.OnSiteTill,
            Number = s.Number,
            Type = s.Type,
        })
            .ToList();
        return Json(events);
    }
```

When I break the code I got correct values in arrays (int,date,date,string,string)

But when I call data AJAX style I get all values except ID, which is on alert out as undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        var now = moment();
        var nextMonth = now.clone().add(1, 'month');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/home/GetEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    alert(v.ID);
                    events.push({
                        Description: ("Number: " + v.Number + ", Type: " + v.Type).link("Projects/Edit/" + v.ID),
                        start: moment(v.onSite),
                        // add one day due to excluding end date in callendar
                        end: v.onSiteTill != null ? moment(v.onSiteTill).add('days', 1) : null,
                        ,
                        allDay: true
                    });

                })......
```

Its driving me crazy, I tried to change int to string in controler still getting undefined, also put ID = s.ID as comment and it did not even make any difference (of course the data was not in array).

Could you please help?

Marek

Comment: It's probably `id`, not `ID`, once it is serialized to JSON.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on `alert(v.ID)`, or `console.log(v)` to actually inspect the object?